# AS3 - target variable using another variable string value

Tags: string, actionscript-3, variables, target

okay. so i have a function and i've passed a parameter through it called  **objectName**.
no i have no idea how to do this or explain it. so here goes.

```
public function moveObject(ObjectName):void{


           //objectName now holds "myName" which is an object also

           //i would now like my variable called myNamePosition to equal 10

           //so it would need to grab the value of objectName which is myName:Object.
           //turn it into a string of some kind - myName:string
           //add "Position" to the end of it so its myNamePosition
           // make it equal to 10

           trace(myNamePosition);

    }
```

The functions parameters passed through would change so i cant actually use "myName". but rather "objectName".

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
package
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;


public class astest extends MovieClip
{
    public function astest()
    {
        init();
    }

    private var myNamePosition:int;
    private function init():void
    {
        moveObject({myName:{}})
    }

    public function moveObject(objectName:Object):void
    {
        var propName:String;
        for(propName in objectName)
            break;
        trace(propName);

        propName+="Position";
        trace(propName);

        this[propName] = 10;

        var propValue:* = this[propName];
        trace(propValue);
    }   
}
}
```

output:

```
myName
myNamePosition
10
```

Is it what you need?

Comment: Almost. i think. I get an error : ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property myNamePosition on game.

the error comes from "this[propName] = 10"

Comment: I'd like myNamePosition to take the value of 10.

Comment: _this[propName]_ is a reference to the property of class instance or variable in the fla file. Error meas that you haven't such variable.